# Google Sheets COUNTIF syntax across different tabs

Tags: syntax, google-sheets, countif

I am currently trying to work out how to make the current Google Sheets version of COUNTIF properly count how many times the value of a cell (C3) is higher than the value if another cell (E3), according to the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF('4'!$C$3,">'4'!$E$3")
```

You'll note that the formula is run in a different tab than the one where the cells being counted are located in (which is named "4"). The formula returns a zero `'0'`, when it should be returning a one `'1'`, as the value in `'4'!$C$3` actually is higher than the value in `'4'!$E$3`. 
Clearly, I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I'-'I Yes! You're the effing best. Thanks for the edit-tip.

Comment: So, the user I'-'I (https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/i-i) suggested the following edit: 

=COUNTIF('4'!$C$3,">'4'!$E$3") --> COUNTIF('4'!$C$3,">"&'4'!$E$3)

This suggestion resolved my issue, but I can't find his suggestion anymore, nor do I know how to mark my question as 'resolved'.

Comment: You can answer your own question or delete it. Personally I would go with the latter because I am mot sure whether a fix on a typo constitutes a good answer that can help future users. `&` concatenates strings in case you wonder.

Comment: @Argyll - Thanks for the tip and suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the user I'-'I (stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/i-i) suggested the following edit:

```
=COUNTIF('4'!$C$3,">'4'!$E$3") --> COUNTIF('4'!$C$3,">"&'4'!$E$3)
```

This suggestion resolved my issue.